# How to filter xml based on multiple fields

Tags: xslt

I need help with filtering the job_information records by only getting the end_date = 9999-12-31 and if action is not equal to "DELETE"

The input XML is as follows

```
queryCompoundEmployeeResponse  
CompoundEmployee  
Person  
fields...fields  
fields...fields  
fields...fields  
Employment_Information  
fields...fields  
fields...fields  
      job_information
      Action..Action
      date...date  
      job_information
      Action...Action
      date...date
```

I am getting stuck trying to do it

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="employment_information">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::job_information)]"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="employment_information[job_information/end_date = 
  '9999-12-31']"/>
</xsl:copy>
```

The following is the input XML

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
      <CompoundEmployee>
      <id></id>
      <person>
      <employment_information>
      <action>NO CHANGE</action>
      <assignment_class></assignment_class>
      <job_information>
      <action>NO CHANGE</action>
      <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
      <event>5</event>
      </job_information>
      <job_information>
      <action>DELETE</action>
      <end_date>1998-12-31</end_date>
      <event>5</event>
      </job_information>
      </employment_information>
      </person>
      <execution_timestamp>2018-09-18T12:06:05.000Z</execution_timestamp>
      <version_id></version_id>
     </CompoundEmployee>
    </queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

The output should be the following XML. The 2nd job_information should be removed

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
      <CompoundEmployee>
      <id></id>
      <person>
      <employment_information>
      <action>NO CHANGE</action>
      <assignment_class></assignment_class>
      <job_information>
      <action>NO CHANGE</action>
      <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
      <event>5</event>
      </job_information>
      </employment_information>
      </person>
      <execution_timestamp>2018-09-18T12:06:05.000Z</execution_timestamp>
      <version_id></version_id>
     </CompoundEmployee>
    </queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

Comment: Please post an example input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: I have posted the example input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> filtering the job_information records by only getting the end_date = 9999-12-31 and if action is not equal to "DELETE"

I think that could be translated to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="job_information[not(end_date = '9999-12-31' and action != 'DELETE')]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

This *removes* the `job_information` elements you don't want.  To do it the way you started - i.e. *keep* the `job_information` elements you want, it would need to be:

```
<xsl:template match="employment_information">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::job_information)]"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="job_information[end_date = '9999-12-31' and action != 'DELETE']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that this could change the original order of the elements, since the wanted `job_information` elements will always be at the end.